# Fabric java SDK New channel foo error. StatusValue 400

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I used Mac OS.
When I was running Fabric java SDK，I met this Error：New channel foo error. StatusValue 400. Status BAD_REQUEST。How to fix it？

Answer (score 1):

Checking the docker logs for the orderer will help. to do this, get the containerid of the orderer by running

```
$ docker ps
```

Then, check the logs for the  by running

```
$ docker logs <containerid>
```

Some potential reasons are:

- that the channel name has illegal characters (e.g. channelAllowedChars = "[a-z][a-z0-9.-]*", from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/0631ccd2b1e30f56088dd3905a78bfb73a93ed51/common/configtx/manager.go).
- The client that's being used to create the channel does not have the proper user context and thus fails certificate validation (needs to be a valid peer organization user with an MSPID to allow the certifcate and key to be verified).

Comment: Thank you.Thank you.Thank you.